# How add margin bottom symbol for makerLine of ECHARTS

Tags: echarts

I need to add padding between the `symbol` and `Xaxis`,
And code here

```
       markLine: {silent: true,
        symbolSize:5,
        data: [
          {
            name : "symbol Bottom",
            xAxis : dates[dates.length-3]
            symbolSize:30
        }]}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxM8H.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the xAxis. Check it out [this](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.padding).

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    axisLabel: {
        padding: 10,
    }
},
```